# How do automotive engines differ for longitudinal vs. transverse applications?

Tags: automotive-engineering

Sometimes engines are described as being intended for a particular orientation, e.g., "The 4.6 L; 278.6 cu in (4,565 cc) LD8 (VIN "Y") is a transverse V8 for front-wheel drive cars." What exactly does that entail? Why would an engine function differently with transverse instead of longitudinal mounting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design of the engine ie a 90 degree v takes more space than a 60 degree v then the total length of the engine plays a part as well as how the transmission is attached.

Comment: Ok, so an engine designed for transverse applications could in principle be mounted longitudinally, but that would probably be less convenient due to packaging considerations. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks, how do longitudinally and tranversely oriented engines differ. Allow me to explain.

The primary mechanical differences relate to MOUNT positioning and HARMONIC BALANCE. The timing cover may differ as well as valve covers, intake and exhaust manifolds, and connections for hoses and wiring harnesses. In this case, it has nothing to do with the angle of the cylinder orientation (as another poster had commented).

Although you only asked about the engine, I am compelled to emphasize that drivetrain pairing is a significant consideration with chassis dynamics and performance. Generally, transverse orientations are paired with transaxles while longitudinal motors are paired to transmissions. However, there are exceptions to every rule and the late 70's Cadillac Eldorado and early 90's Acura Legend are two interesting examples of longitudinal front wheel drive vehicles you can examine for further study.

If you have a more specific inquiry on this subject matter, I am happy to help.